# Can't get json object using swiftyJSON

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I'm using alamofire 4 and swiftyJson. Using this code arr always is empty. Why?

```
network.request("https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/discover/ayml/", method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON { (response) in

        let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)

        var arr = swiftyJsonVar["groups"][0]["items"]
    }
```

json response is here https://pastebin.com/EJsuYEjD

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your response. It contains 10 items! The way I checked:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "file", withExtension: "txt")!
let data: Data = try! Data.init(contentsOf: url)
let json = JSON(data: data)
let groups = json["groups"][0]["items"]
```

I think `swiftyJsonVar` might be invalid or you receive some other response, not the one you provided

Comment: Maybe. Or maybe they look at what's in arr outside of the closure, but the request is asynchronous... so arr is empty. ;) They need to explain more and show their real code.

Comment: @EricAya that is true. I've missed that fact (: